# Stuck on how to make text appear as "assets" enter circle

Tags: python, pgzero

Making a small game through pygame zero. trying to get text to appear on "assets" as they enter the circle. Have tried different methods with rect but end up with errors. This is apart of my code. Have been using Pygame-zero to try and work through my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def update():
    global score
    global v
    global radius
    global b
    #to move robot
    if keyboard.right:
        v = v + 0.1
    if keyboard.left:
        v = v - 0.1
    if keyboard.up:
        radius = radius + 10
    if keyboard.down:
       radius = radius - 10
    robot.right += v
    if robot.right > 400 + radius:
           robot.left = 400 - radius
    if keyboard.a:
        robot.right += -b
    if keyboard.l:
        robot.right += b

       #to drop asssets
    for asset in assets:
        asset.y += 1.2
    for asset in assets:
        if asset.colliderect(robot):
            score += 150
            assets.remove(asset)

    #to calculate distance between robot and asset

        # elif keyboard.k_1:
        #     bias = bias + 0.1
        # elif keyboard.k_0:
        #     bias = bias - 0.1

def draw():
    screen.fill((BLACK))
    screen.draw.circle((400,600),radius,(220,20,60))
    for asset in assets:
        asset.draw()
    robot.draw()
    drawScore()

pgzrun.go()
```